# Update SQL Table via Setup File in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, magento

I have a custom extension for magento with a custom table that adds to the Magento SQL database via the install/setup custom extension file. Works.

NOTE: I also have used the upgrade script technique (in other custom extensions) to add attributes/rows etc to the other custom extensions database table (in other custom extensions). See below the code used in the update script.

```
changed config.xml version value to next increment
```

then the update script (myextension_setup/upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php)

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycustomtable'),
'mycustomtable_new_data',
array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'comment' => 'My Custom Table ID'
)
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The above code works and adds the new sql row to the table.

The problem is the custom extension im working on has maxed out on the id (auto increment) row and is causing php errors/timeouts(in apache log) etc in the admin (causing white screen of death) as there are 30000+ id, *we'll thats what im presuming* as setting the etc/module to false has the admin back up and running.

The admin dashboard has multiple blocks that queries & filters this table using Mage::getModel('myextension/myextension')->getCollection()

Below is the sql **install** script that adds the id field to the database

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
```

- bigint?

How would i use a upgrade script to update this row/field to increase the amount of IDs allowed? Or maybe im completely off and the issue is accessing that amount of data various times on page load?

Comment: Integer value will allow more than 1 million.

Comment: Narrowed it down to a few of the collection sets (filtered results via Mage::getModel('myextension/myextension')->getCollection()) requesting a count of items that outputs a return value. Basically the issue is returning a count() value from 30000+ ids twice on a page load as well as other queries to the same table.

Comment: You mean same id appearing two times? If it so, check for the join..

Comment: No i mean i have two sections on a admin page and both use a collection() to echo a count() value, which the collection is 30000+ ids so attempting those process on page load on a server with 128MB ram (i think) just causes the issues..